# Failure to export graphics by right-click when Notebook magnification is changed

Tags: graphics, front-end, export, bugs, image

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 or earlier and persisting through 11.0.1 or later**

---

When I try to export graphics as PNG, JPG and other rasterized formats using the right-click and choosing `Save Graphic As...`, if the notebook magnification is changed from 100%, *Mathematica* fails to export the image and returns the following error:

> The specified setting for the option WindowSize cannot be used.

However this does not happen when `Export` function is used to export the graphic.

[image: screenshot]

I think this is a bug.

I am using *Mathematica* 9.0.1 installed on Microsoft Windows 7 (64-bit).

Comment: Try to figure out steps to reliably reproduce the error and [let Wolfram know about it](http://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/email/)

Comment: Is this the same issue as: [(55001)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55001)?  If so I should close my own as a duplicate.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes. I believe it is the same issue. The error message is the same. However I think that your question should not be closed, because this question mentions using `Save Graphic As...` not `Save Selection As...`. I think the two questions are related and your question is not duplicate.

Comment: Perfect! This works!

Comment: I get these error messages all the time when I save output cells in PNG format. I just ignore them. The PNG files are fine.

Comment: @Karsten answer?

Comment: @m_goldberg under Win 7 this error message prevents the creation of the PNG file. Are you using OSX or Linux?

Comment: @Karsten7. OS X.

Comment: But still present in 10.0.1

Comment: Bug still not fixed in 10.2.0 - confirmed on Windows 7 (64 Bit).

Comment: @Karsten7 Still not fixed in 11.0? Seriously what are they doing back there!  FIX THE DAMN BUGS BEFORE ADDING MORE FEATURES.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have the same problem with the Windows version 11.0.1.0

Answer (score 17):

I have reported this as a bug and it's confirmed.

Answer (score 10):

Here are three ways to change the magnification without breaking **Save Graphic As...**:

1. Changing the magnification of the current notebook by executing

   ```
   SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], Magnification -> 1.5]
   ```
2. Changing the magnification used during the current session by executing

   ```
   SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, Magnification -> 1.5]
   ```
3. Persistently changing the magnification of all future front end sessions by executing

   ```
   SetOptions[$FrontEnd, Magnification -> 1.5]
   ```

(If the `"MagnificationPopUp"` in the lower right corner of the window still shows `100%`, that now means 100% of 150% magnification.)

---

There are three ways to solve this problem after one used the  `"MagnificationPopUp"` in the lower right corner of the window or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>mouse wheel</kbd> to change the magnification:

1. Use `Export` instead of "Save Selection As ...", e.g.

   ```
   Export[FileNameJoin[{NotebookDirectory[], "graphic.png"}], %]
   ```
2. Change the notebook magnification in the lower right corner of the notebook window to `100%`.
3. Use the menu Window ▶ Magnification to select any of the listed magnifications.