# My "N" turned red randomly

Tags: syntax, syntax-highlighting

For some reason my N function showed up in red even though I haven't noticed it in that color before. The color actually makes the code much more readable but I just don't know if I should be alarmed or not.

[image: Red N function]

I applied a different stylesheet to my notebook (as you can tell by the color of the input I've been modding my own stylesheet) but the color is still there. I also checked on the Appearance tab of Edit > Preference and the only red syntax are the errors. I doubt "N" falls into any of these and I also can't tell which shade of red it is to match it to.

[image: Preference syntax error]

**Update**: this is getting weirder:

After restarting MMA, the N is no longer red :'( Also, I can't seem to File > Save Selection As without setting the window size to 100%. If the size is not 100%, I got the error that "The specified setting for the option WindowSize cannot be used."

[image: Window size error]

This was reported to be a [bug](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16539/mathematica-9-fails-to-export-graphics-by-right-click-when-notebook-magnificatio) so I suspect my red "N" is also a bug (because previously, with the red N, I could save my selections at sizes that were not 100%). It was nice while it lasted I guess, though I really hope WRI adds better syntax highlighting in their future releases.

Comment: Hello, this is not a bug. You probably had another symbol named `N` that was on your path and _Mathematica_ was warning you about potential name collisions or shadowing. Please see my answer in the linked duplicate for an explanation and a reproducible example.

Comment: If you liked the red coloring because it helped you identify built-in symbols easily, you can do it the following way: Evaluate ``SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 "AutoStyleOptions" -> {"SymbolContextStyles" -> {"System`" -> Magenta}}]`` (change to your favourite color) and use it for a while. If you like how it works, change `$FrontEndSession` to `$FrontEnd` and this will persist across sessions.

Comment: I can't seem to evaluate your expression. I got the error that "Syntax::tsntxi: "[$FrontEndSession,AutoStyleOptions->{SymbolContextStyles->{System`->Magenta}}]" is incomplete; more input is needed."

Comment: Update: I forgot to include the SetOptions in front. Oops! I got it now. This trick is so awesome! Where can I go to find out more of this hack?

Comment: Another update: I tried to change the color to a more pleasing magenta by using the code with the RGBColor values: SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 "AutoStyleOptions" -> {"SymbolContextStyles" -> {"System`" -> 
      RGBColor[211, 54, 130]}}]. However, the highlighting became white. I'm not really sure why it turned out that way :/

Comment: Ok I figured out why. The RGBColor only accepts values between 0 and 1, so whatever value that I got that are based on the 255 scale (I got my Solarized colors from here: http://www.zovirl.com/2011/07/22/solarized_cheat_sheet/) have to be divided by 255 e.g. RGBColor[211/255, 54/255, 130/255]. Thank you rm -rf for all the help. Really appreciate it!