# Change Default Font Color of Commands

Tags: graphics

I encountered to two problems with *Mathematica*:

one: How can I change the default font color of commands and functions in *Mathematica* (which is black) to another color, so that whenever I wanted to write that command, the color of that, changes automatically? Actually, how can I set all define commands or functions with a specified color?

Second: I want to copy a command from *Mathematica* into *Microsoft Word* For example the bellow one:

```
Plot[x^2 + 1, {x, 1, 5}]
```

I have colored `Plot` with Red and `x` is shown Green by default in *Mathematica*.

But when I copy this command to *Word*, all of those will be black; and if I want them colored I have to color them in the *Word* again.

Comment: You can control syntax coloring in Edit > Preferences > Appearance, and you can also make adjustments using stylesheets, though that's a pretty broad topic that you'd need to read up on. Unfortunately, though, I don't think there is a way to preserve text styling from Mathematica to Word.

Comment: thanks a bunch for your guidance, but Unfortunately, there is not any possibility for changing the color of the commands themselves, for example: 'Plot', 'Do','If', 'Table' and so on which can not be changed in color. By your suggested way, there is just possibility for changing the color of variables

Comment: This is not strictly limited to "commands", but if you add a style called "Input" in your stylesheet that will be pretty close.

Comment: See [this Q/A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48856/125) and Q/As linked there.

Comment: @kguler going for more kisses? :)

Comment: To copy `Plot[x^2 + 1, {x, 1, 5}]` into Word why can't you just copy and paste? To copy equations select Copy As > MathML and paste that int the equation editor in Word.