# installing solarised stylesheet!

Tags: stylesheet, installation

I have recently stumbled upon your solarised stylesheet for mathematica!
I've been having some trouble installing the dark themed version of it!

This is my first time using stylesheets and it is all kinda new to me.
Somehow only the light version comes up.

I am using version 10.0 if this makes any difference.

Please let me know!

best of wishes,

Alex

PS NOTE: The following question relates to the solarised stylesheet as made by seismatica in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5846/resources-for-beautiful-mathematica-stylesheets) post. The answer in the end was rather simple.
Simply going from Format-> Screen Environment-> Dark.
That's it! Sorry for answering my own question!

Cheers all

Comment: Alex, to what stylesheet are you referring? Where did you find it? How did you install it, and what trouble are you experiencing? Please note also that this forum is *not* connected with or run by with Wolfram Support.

Comment: hi MarcoB!
I'm actually really sorry! I thought I was asking a question directly to the person who wrote a stylesheet! Also, much to my shame  i just found the answer to my own question. I was referring to the Solarised stylesheet as made by seismatica. Should I delete this post? Cheers!

Comment: @Alex I was under the impression that it was made by RM, but I might be wrong.

Comment: ah maybe!
I apologise to the author! I got my names wrong!

Comment: @Alex Then take a look at this post by Seismatica as well: [Solarized stylesheet and other goodies](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/49193/27951), which I will suggest as a duplicate of your current post.

Comment: @Alex based upon Marco's comment, I think you're correct as to the author.