# Gallery of different style cells?

Tags: cells, stylesheet, style

I'm looking for some nice new cell styles for my stylesheets, are there any galleries of cells from which I can mix and match?

Comment: Have you gone to **Format** > **Stylesheet** > **Stylesheet Chooser** and looked at all the included styles?  That's a fair number of examples.

Comment: Or are you looking for external sources? [**49193**](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/49193/5478) If so, then we could mark it as a duplicate of [5846](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5846/5478), what do you think user5601?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I was hoping for a set of individual examples per type, not an particular stylesheets, and yes the old Stylesheet Chooser option is very tired.

Comment: By type you mean a stylesheet? If you click "New" in a stylesheet chooser you will get a large example with those cells.

Comment: No I mean by cell type, I'd love to see many examples for just 'quote' or 'code' cells so I can pick and choose... this might be asking too much I think

Comment: But you can't just pick a 'code' cell styling from one stylesheet and use it in another. I mean, you can but it won't be the same as cell style is also inherited from a notebook styles, from FormatType styles etc etc. So it does not make sense to talk about a gallery of standalone code cells. P.s. use `@Kuba` if you want me or whover to be notified about your comment. We don't have to because it is your post and you will be anyway.