# Bug report: Attempting to Save Selection As... in a magnified Notebook fails with errors

Tags: front-end, export, notebooks, bugs, image

**Bug introduced in 9.0.1 or earlier and persisting through 10.0.2 or later**

---

I have found that attempting to **Save Selection As...** in a magnified Notebook fails with errors.

On my system it can be easily reproduced by:

1. opening any documentation page
2. setting Notebook magnification to 150%
3. making an arbitrary selection
4. using **Save Selection As...** in the **File** menu
5. attempting to save as a .PNG image

Errors produced in the Messages window:

> ```
> The specified setting for the option WindowSize cannot be used.
>
> During evaluation of In[15]:= Set::shape: Lists 
> {System`ConvertersDump`height$3806,System`ConvertersDump`width$3806}
> and {0} are not the same shape. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[15]:= Image::imgarray: The specified argument
> {} should be an array of rank 2 or 3 with machine-sized numbers. >>
> ```

I am running Mathematica 10.0.0.0 under Windows 7.

Comment: Partially confirmed on "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014)", but only 3 times the message: `The specified setting for the option WindowSize cannot be used.` Have you seen [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindowSize.html)? Wild spelunking, but WindowSize and Magnification do not like each other?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [(16539)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16539)

Comment: Do I spy a *hat* now? Very fetching!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No bug for me with v.10.0.2 on OS X 10.9.5. I can use `Save Selection As` in the File menu or `Save Graphic As` in the menu displayed after right-click, I can choose PNG or JPEG, the image saved reproduce exactly what is on screen (with the same magnification or pixels size). (There is just this message on the Messages console : "The specified setting for the option WindowSize cannot be used.")

Comment: @Mr.Wizard "Just for fun" I did the same tests with the Suggestions Bar enabled (in the Pref. menu) ... I am still able to save images but the size (pixel dimensions) of these saved images do not correspond anymore to the size displayed on the screen. Actually the size for saved images is now the same whatever the magnification is. However the font size (labels), and the thickness of the line do correspond to what is on the screen (for the test I am plotting Sin[x]).

Comment: @SquareOne Thanks for the report.