# Version 11 cannot print properly?

Tags: bugs, printing

**Bug introduced in 10.0 and persisting through 11.2 or later**

---

I have two problems with printing in version 10.

First, I can't print correctly with a setting of printing scale

For example, I have some plots in a notebook,

```
Grid@Table[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, ImageSize -> Medium], {4}, {4}]
```

[image]

when I print with scale 70%,

[image]

I get something like

[image]

I always get a big blank at the top of the page, no matter what I set the margins in the printing options dialog.

Second, the curve seems to be stretched after print.

Here is compare between screen shot of the figure in the notebook and after print

[image]
[image]

You can see that the curve in the printed version stretches out beyond the frame.

Are there ways around these problems? Currently I have to switch to older version once I need  to print something.

The example notebook is [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/8263c173-24de-455a-9491-3b161ecc4a72)

I'm using 10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 29, 2014) on OS X 10.9.4.

Comment: Possibly related: [(16539)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16539), [(24525)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24525), [(55001)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55001)

Comment: I do see this too on OS X 10.8.5 and version 10. The "stretching" is not really stretching, it's an incorrect `PlotRangeClipping`. And I only see it when the page orientation is landscape, not portrait. I would say this wrong clipping is a bug.  The other printing issues with the space and the plot not fitting on the page are very annoying and long-standing problems that I don't have a good general solution for, either... except to export plots one at a time instead of printing the notebook.

Comment: @Jens Thanks for confirming that :)

Comment: workaround windows xp virtual machine running mathematica

Comment: @William No bug under windows XP for version 10.1?

Comment: Now that you have 10.2, can you retest?

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks for the reminder, I have updated the post.

Comment: @xslittlegrass Version 10 gave us undo, maybe version 11 will have print!

Comment: @M.R. I hope we don't need a [campaign](http://undo-for-mathematica.alaifari.com/) to get us print!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: This [continues to be an issue](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102021/37). It's astonishing, but *Mathematica* ***effectively lacks support for printing!***

Comment: @M.R. Well instead of fixing print in version 11, they just introduced 3D print. https://www.wolfram.com/language/11/3d-printing/?product=mathematica  I'm not impressed.

Answer (score 4):

Whenever I print I highlight the bracket on the far right and

right click ->save selection as->PDF (don't forget to delete the "Out[1]=" first)

Then just throw it in your document editor of choice. The Mac default is "Preview."
[image]