# How do I print a notebook without truncation?

Tags: bugs, printing

How do I print my document without truncation of my code and figures? I've tried scaling the document down, but just scales down the size of the text, without expanding into the empty space thus created. Unlike every other application on known to humankind, *Mathematica* neither prints what one sees on the screen, nor does it print what it can on the page, but preforms arbitrary scaling and truncation that seems unrelated to either.

For example, my code and figures get cut off long before they reach the (standard .75") margin (in gray) in my printout:

[image: fig]

Scaling things down (necessary anyway, since otherwise printing is *huge*; Page Setup > Scale) further retains the truncation (while oddly rewrapping the code, but still truncating it):

[image]

For reference, this is what it *should* look like:

[image]

What settings do I need to use to get Mathematica to print the full screen with of my notebook. That is, to scale so that the width of the window I'm printing from is taken as the width of the document as printed, so that the wrapping I see in the screen is what I see in the printout, and so that figures are not truncated?

Comment: You know that you can use `BarcodeRecognize` to move on to the next stage of the challenge :-)!

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar: Yep, but it get's less fun (as a coding challenge) after that.

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar: As is typical for *Mathematica* 10% of the time was spent on the substance of the problem (and MMA was very helpful with that); 90% was spent on getting the simplest things (like printing) to work (and I've almost given up on the latter). Note to self: *Python*!

Comment: My solution involves generating large numbers of permutations and is unworkably slow.  You're obviously a more suitable candidate.  As to your actual question, if I print with `Print Settings -> Show Page Breaks` (and `Printing Environment -> Printout`) the printed page is more reasonably scaled (but the screen display is correspondingly shrunken).  Perhaps bypassing the print functionality and `Export`ing to PDF is the way to go?

Comment: PS This is probably a [duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57182).