# How to save all notebook outputs as pdf file

Tags: front-end, export, notebooks, pdf-format

I have produced a lot of graphs and tables in my notebook. I am trying to save all these outputs as pdf file. As we know form [Rodney](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16539/failure-to-export-graphics-by-right-click-when-notebook-magnification-is-changed)  and form [Mr. Wizard](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55001/bug-report-attempting-to-save-selection-as-in-a-magnified-notebook-fails-wit) , we can not use save as function. I have adobe acrobat PDF writer. When I use my PDF writer to print notebook, it cannot print.

I can delete all my input cells and leave outputs only. Then, I can go to file  and select save as and save as type as my .pdf.

How can I save entire notebook that has only outputs without deleting input cells? (I have many figures and tables. Combining them while exporting should not change look of my tables and figures)

We can make one table and one graph for illustration purpose and export both at one time without affecting their format.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: *Just* the outputs, or the entire Notebook?

Comment: myFig = Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 1}]; Export[".../Desktop/myFig.pdf", myFig, "PDF"] but we cannot import pdf to StackExchange (just bmp and a few other formats).

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, I want just output. By the say, all figures and tables in one pdf file at one time. Thank you.

Comment: @ David, is it possible for you to answer this question? I have over 25 figures and over 10 tables. I want to export all in one file at one time. Please, address my concern if possible. Thank you.

Comment: You could group all your figures into a single GraphicsGrid[] and export that.

Comment: myFigs = Table[Plot[Sin[i x], {x, -2, 2}], {i, 12}]; FinalFig = GraphicsGrid[Partition[myFigs, 3]]; Export["/.../Desktop/FinalFig.pdf", FinalFig, "PDF"]

Comment: You can select all output cells with `NotebookFind[EvaluationNotebook[], "Output", All, CellStyle];` and then `Save Selection As...`. I hope someone remember how to do it fully automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**

I was thinking about some automation of your request. With the the following approach you 
can create a new notebook, show your tables and graphs and save a new notebook as PDF.

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
some Code
...
some Code
```

List all global variables, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727592/list-all-global-variables):

```
names = Select[Names["Global`*"], Head@Symbol[#] =!= Symbol && Head@Symbol[#] =!= Function &]

(*
{"a0", "a1", "a2", "plo1", "plo2", "plo3", "plo4", "plo5", "plo6", "plo7", "tab1", "tf1"}
*)
```

You can then select the variables and reuse with ToExpression as Language input.

```
print = names[[4 ;; Length[names]]] // ToExpression // TableForm;
```

Use CreateDocument to open a document notebook and pass “print” as expression to that file.

```
nb = CreateDocument[print];
```

Then you can export the document created, as usual to PDF

```
Export["printPDF.pdf", %]
```

The result with my settings:

[image]

---

Say you have two notebooks open, one named Work.nb, the other Print.nb, on a fresh Kernel of course. With Work.nb you do all your graphs and tables. All required elements must have a unique variable name:

```
tab1 = Text[
  Grid[Table[
    With[{n = n}, 
     With[{u = HoldForm[\[Integral]1/(x^n - 1) \[DifferentialD]x]}, 
      TraditionalForm /@ {u, ReleaseHold[u]}]], {n, 4}], Frame -> All,
    ItemSize -> Automatic, Background -> LightYellow]]
```

[image]

```
    plo1 = Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -π, π}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> {Range[-π, π, π/2], Automatic}]
```

[image]

```
plo2 = Plot[1/2 x^3 - 7 x + 4, {x, -5, 6}]
```

[image]

Because all kind variables are available in all open notebooks, you can also recall it in the notebook Print.nb. In the first line you can query the variables you need;

```
tab1
GraphicsGrid[{{plo1, plo2}}]
f[5] + f[π]
g[x + 1]
plo2
```

The result might look like this:

[image]

Done so, it will be easy to save Print.nb as PDF.

Comment: @ Lou, thank you for your time and answer. I am sorry for being so late  to get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on my answer at [Referencing cells after reopening a saved notebook](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/95892/referencing-cells-after-reopening-a-saved-notebook/119160#119160), get a list of all output cell expressions with

```
outputs = ToExpression[#, StandardForm, Defer] & @@@ 
          (NotebookRead /@ Cells[CellStyle -> "Output"]);
```

then export via

```
Export["outputs.pdf", Column[outputs], "PDF"];
```

Comment: Instead of `ToExpression` (which can change the appearance of the contents and sometimes simply [fails](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112392/280)) you could simply `Map` `RawBoxes`: `outputs = RawBoxes /@ 
  NotebookRead /@ Cells[CellStyle -> "Output"]; Export["outputs.pdf", 
 Column[outputs]];`.

Answer (score 1):

```
myFigs = Table[Plot[Sin[i x], {x, -2, 2}], {i, 6}];
myTables = 
  Table[Grid[
    RandomInteger[20, {RandomInteger[10], RandomInteger[10]}], 
    Frame -> All], {6}];
FinalFig = GraphicsGrid[Partition[Union[myFigs, myTables], 3]];
Export[".../Desktop/FinalFig.pdf", FinalFig, "PDF"];
```

Comment: @ David, thank you for taking time to answer this question. It helps me but it also leaves some of my concerns unanswered. For example, when I combined my figures and tables, outlook of figures and tables changes. If I could save entire notebook only with outputs, it would save my life.

Comment: Then use NotebookWrite[] around each figure and table, writing them to a single Notebook (thereby preserving the format of each).  Then use SaveAs... pdf for that output notebook.

Comment: Thank you David for you suggestion. I will follow.