# ToExpression and ToBoxes aren't inverses of each other?

Tags: conversion, boxes, language-design

Applying `ToExpression` and `ToBoxes` repeatedly to `Hold[1/1]` gives many `1`, which seems strange.

```
In[11]:= Nest[(ToExpression[ToBoxes[#]] &), Hold[1/1], 10]

Out[11]= Hold[1 (1 (1 (1 (1 (1 (1 (1 (1 (1 (1 x 1/1))))))))))]
```

This only happens with a denominator of `1`.  Is it a bug?  I'm using Mathematica `10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 30, 2014)`.

EDIT: A better question would be: how can I avoid this accumulation?  But presumably the answer would just be "use a pattern to detect that special case"...

Comment: You're right, `Hold[1/1]` is treated differently, apparently multiplied by `1` (checked for version 8). But is there any place in the docs that says `ToExpression` and `ToBoxes` are inverses of each other? I don't think that's what defines them.

Comment: Yes, I don't believe this is ever claimed in the docs.

Comment: Perhaps the question makes no sense.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I already upvoted the first version...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### It is well-documented!

According to the Documentation page for [`StandardForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StandardForm.html),

> - `StandardForm` generates output that gives a unique and unambiguous
>     representation of Wolfram Language expressions, suitable for use as
>     input. »
> - `StandardForm` is the standard format type used for both input and
>     output of Wolfram Language expressions in notebooks.
> - `StandardForm` is based on boxes.

And then under the "Properties & Relations" section:

> Use `ToBoxes` to get the box representation of an expression in `StandardForm`:
>
> ```
> ToBoxes[x^2 + y^3, StandardForm]
> ```
>
> > ```
> > RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["x", "2"], "+", SuperscriptBox["y", "3"]}]
> > ```
>
> Use `ToExpression` to convert back:
>
> ```
> ToExpression[%]
> ```
>
> > ```
> > x^2 + y^3
> > ```

Based on the above I would say that it is well-documented that `ToExpression` and `ToBoxes` are inverses of each other **when we work exclusively in the `StandardForm`** (and the expression won't change during evaluation).

If one still isn't completely convinced, I would cite also Documentation pages for `MakeExpression` (which `ToExpression` uses under the hood) and `MakeBoxes` (which `ToBoxes` uses under the hood):

> - `MakeBoxes` is the low-level function used in Wolfram System sessions to convert expressions into boxes.
> - `MakeExpression` is used whenever boxes are supplied as input to the Wolfram Language.
>
> Use `MakeExpression` to obtain the original expression in a held form:
>
> ```
> MakeBoxes[1 + 1, StandardForm]
> ```
>
> > ```
> > RowBox[{"1", "+", "1"}]
> > ```
>
> ```
> MakeExpression[%, StandardForm]
> ```
>
> > ```
> > HoldComplete[1 + 1]
> > ```

#### Summary

`StandardForm` is the default form used in Wolfram System notebooks which provides a **unique and unambiguous** representation of Wolfram Language expressions, suitable for use as input. On the low level it is based on boxes and one can convert any WL expression into boxes using `MakeBoxes` and then get the original expression backward in the held form using `MakeExpression`.

So the **actual** functions which (when working exclusively in the `StandardForm`) are exact inverses for each other are `MakeBoxes` and `MakeExpression`. Their only difference from `ToBoxes` and `ToExpression` is that they don't evaluate the expression.

### Your particular issue

The issue you have encountered is indeed a minor bug.

You can fix it by making the following specific definition for `MakeExpression`:

```
MakeExpression[FractionBox["1", "1"], StandardForm] = HoldComplete[Divide[1, 1]];
```

Now

```
Nest[(ToExpression[ToBoxes[#]] &), Hold[1/1], 10]
```

> ```
> Hold[1 1/1]
> ```

and

```
Nest[(ToExpression[ToBoxes[#]] &), Hold[Divide[1, 1]], 10]
```

> ```
> Hold[1/1]
> ```

If you wish to fix also the conversion of `Hold[1/1]` input to `Hold[1 1/1]`, you can add to the above a definition which will treat the `1/1` input in a special way:

```
MakeExpression[RowBox[{"1", "/", "1"}], StandardForm] = HoldComplete[Divide[1, 1]];
```

Now

```
Hold[1/1]
```

> ```
> Hold[1/1]
> ```

```
Nest[(ToExpression[ToBoxes[#]] &), Hold[1/1], 10]
```

> ```
> Hold[1/1]
> ```

A word of warning: I'm not absolutely sure that this solution is free from unexpected side-effects and won't break something in the system. If you encounter any issue, please let me know.

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as to make the claim that `ToBoxes` and `ToExpression` are inverse operations.  I wouldn't even make that claim about `MakeBoxes` and `MakeExpression`.  Expressions can have many representations in StandardForm, but necessarily, `MakeBoxes` must choose one canonical representation. Also, it's easy to create things which are not inverses, so even some sort of weaker statement must emphasize that this is *convention*, not a dictate.  Finally, there are some boxes, most notably `TemplateBox`, which require FE secret sauce to properly convert into expressions.

Comment: @JohnFultz In which situations we can be sure that `MakeBoxes` and `MakeExpression` **are** inverses for each other (technically, i.e. in the sense of the original question)?

Comment: There are simply no guarantees.  Anybody can make any `MakeBoxes` and `MakeExpression` rules they want.  The system enforces no contracts here.  So, at best, your question only makes sense for what is *typically* true for *built-in* rules.  Working under that assumption, there's still no guarantee that `MakeExpression`/`MakeBoxes` applied to a given set of boxes will return those boxes.  There can't be.  There's too many variations of boxes that produce a given expression (whitespace, comments, operators vs. fullform, prefix/infix/postfix, etc.).

Comment: So the only sensible variation of this question which can be asked is, are there conventions that guarantee, for a given expression, that `MakeBoxes`/`MakeExpression` will return the same expression.  No, it is not guaranteed, although we do try.  `TemplateBox` is a problem because only the FE authoritatively knows about them, but we do build in rules that do sensible things (and, in response to this question, we're updating those rules for the next release).  But there are other cases, like size-limited output, or boxes with elided output (e.g., `InterpolatingFunction`) which still fail.

Answer (score 3):

Comments posted by [John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/309/john-fultz) in reply to [Alexey Popkov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/280/alexey-popkov), preserved for the record:

> I wouldn't go so far as to make the claim that `ToBoxes` and `ToExpression` are inverse operations.  I wouldn't even make that claim about `MakeBoxes` and `MakeExpression`.  Expressions can have many representations in StandardForm, but necessarily, `MakeBoxes` must choose one canonical representation. Also, it's easy to create things which are not inverses, so even some sort of weaker statement must emphasize that this is *convention*, not a dictate.  Finally, there are some boxes, most notably `TemplateBox`, which require FE secret sauce to properly convert into expressions. – John Fultz Sep 7 '16 at 13:48
>
> There are simply no guarantees.  Anybody can make any `MakeBoxes` and `MakeExpression` rules they want.  The system enforces no contracts here.  So, at best, your question only makes sense for what is *typically* true for *built-in* rules.  Working under that assumption, there's still no guarantee that `MakeExpression`/`MakeBoxes` applied to a given set of boxes will return those boxes.  There can't be.  There's too many variations of boxes that produce a given expression (whitespace, comments, operators vs. fullform, prefix/infix/postfix, etc.). – John Fultz Sep 12 '16 at 7:15
>
> So the only sensible variation of this question which can be asked is, are there conventions that guarantee, for a given expression, that `MakeBoxes`/`MakeExpression` will return the same expression.  No, it is not guaranteed, although we do try.  `TemplateBox` is a problem because only the FE authoritatively knows about them, but we do build in rules that do sensible things (and, in response to this question, we're updating those rules for the next release).  But there are other cases, like size-limited output, or boxes with elided output (e.g., `InterpolatingFunction`) which still fail. – John Fultz Sep 12 '16 at 7:18