# How to convert arbitrary raw boxes directly into String?

Tags: notebooks, cells, conversion, boxes, rasterize

This question is motivated by the [recent question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115337/280) about searching inside of the NB files.

According to the Documentation, `ToString` expects a high-level WL expression as the first argument:

```
expr = Row[{Style["Format", Bold], "ted", " string"}]
ToString[expr]
```

> ```
> Formatted string
> ```
>
> ```
> Formatted string
> ```

Unlike `Rasterize` it does not interpret raw boxes as an expression in the low-level box language:

```
cell = Cell[BoxData@ToBoxes@expr, "Output"];
Rasterize[cell]
ToString[cell]
```

> ```
> Cell[BoxData[TemplateBox[{StyleBox["Format", Bold, StripOnInput -> False], "ted", " string"}, RowDefault]], Output]
> ```

Unfortunately `MakeExpression` isn't always able to convert a valid raw boxes into the [corresponding](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112392/280) high-level expression (although in the above simple case it can). Also **conversion from raw boxes into high-level expression breaks the original formatting** (for example, it does not preserve the *infix*, *prefix* and *postfix* notations, and the author's line breaks etc.) and should best be avoided.

**Is it possible to convert arbitrary raw boxes directly into the corresponding `String` without resorting to `MakeExpression`?**

I'm especially interested in converting raw `Cell`s into pure strings for the purposes of [textual searching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115337/280) inside of NB files.

Comment: @Kuba The example is in the question (`cell`). It is about the raw boxes input and the expected output (what `Rasterize` gives as an image which I don't want) and wanted `String` without formatting and suitable for `StringMatchQ` etc.

Comment: @Kuba Since I need to convert all `Cell`s in a Notebook to plaint text, conversion cell-by-cell will be extremely slow (and the final goal is to convert a lot of Notebooks for the purposes of [textual searching](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115337/280) inside of them). Also is it possible to pass the `PageWidth -> Infinity` option somehow? I tried to include it into `Cell` expression and set at the global level but ``FrontEnd`ExportPacket`` ignores it.

Comment: Notebook works too: ``First[FrontEndExecute[
  FrontEnd`ExportPacket[NotebookGet@EvaluationNotebook[], 
   "PlainText"]]]``

Comment: @Kuba That's great! And it seems to have `PageWidth -> Infinity` set by default! You can post this as an answer.

Comment: But don't you feel it would be better to mark it as a duplicate of the linked topic?

Comment: accidentally deleted the comment with the link, here it is: [How can I get the unchanged Box form of an arbitrary expression?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13371/5478)

Comment: @Kuba Current question can be considered as a duplicate of [How do I extract the contents of a selected cell as plain text?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1319/280) but has an emphasis on conversion of a very large amounts of raw boxes into text. The ``FrontEnd`ExportPacket`` solution mostly works but sometimes returns just `Null` (second attempt usually gives success). Do you have any idea how to deal with this problem? It looks like sometimes the call to ``FrontEnd`ExportPacket`` is ended *before* the data is returned. Or may be FrontEnd sometimes just doesn't accept a call?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba) notices in the [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115407/how-to-convert-arbitrary-raw-boxes-directly-into-string?lq=1#comment313163_115407), undocumented [`` FrontEnd`ExportPacket ``](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1411/280) allows conversion of a whole `Notebook` into plain text:

```
nb = NotebookGet@EvaluationNotebook[];
First[FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[nb, "PlainText"]]]
```

> ```
> "nb=NotebookGet@EvaluationNotebook[];
>
> First[FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[nb,\"PlainText\"]]]"
> ```

But it isn't the whole story. Surprisingly FrontEnd evaluates and updates the `Dynamic` objects in the `Notebook` sent as the first argument of `` FrontEnd`ExportPacket ``!

With *Mathematica* 10.4.1 when trying to convert to plain text the "Views.nb" Documentation Notebook (warning: evaluation of the following code can make *Mathematica* not responding for several minutes!)

```
nbWithDynamic = 
  Get@FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "Documentation", "English", 
     "System", "Tutorials", "Views.nb"}];

First[FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[nbWithDynamic, "PlainText"]]];
```

I observe that Kernel downloads a lot of data from the Wolfram paclet server obviously in order to update the `Dynamic` expressions in this Notebook (the most of the data should be due to the second example under the ["SlideView" section](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Views.html#947630944) which downloads shapes for all countries available via `CountryData[]`).

This behavior is especially strange because no `Dynamic` objects from that `Notebook` are displayed on the screen (according to the Documentation, `Dynamic` is updated **only** when displayed on the screen). <del>So this is a bug and serious security violation.</del> (UPDATE: As [explained](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/115407/how-to-convert-arbitrary-raw-boxes-directly-into-string/115488?noredirect=1#comment315002_115488) by John Fultz, exporting in some fundamental sense is equivalent to displaying and this behavior is by design.)

To prevent this one should set the [`DynamicUpdating -> False`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1411/280) option for a `Notebook` before sending it to the FrontEnd:

```
nb = NotebookGet@EvaluationNotebook[];
nbDynamicOff = Insert[nb, DynamicUpdating -> False, 2];
First[FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[nbDynamicOff, "PlainText"]]]
```

> ```
> "nb=NotebookGet@EvaluationNotebook[];
>
> nbDynamicOff=Insert[nb,DynamicUpdating->False,2];
>
> First[FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd`ExportPacket[nbDynamicOff,\"PlainText\"]]]"
> ```

Disabling the `DynamicUpdating` also solves the problem with `` FrontEnd`ExportPacket `` *sometimes* returning just `Null` (but at the second attempt on the same file it returns the expected result). Of course it also speeds up the conversion several times and solves the problem with the `Dynamic updating timeout` dialog appearing during the conversion (what stops the process of computation until you press the "Continue waiting" button).

Comment: Just want to let you know that I've seen your comments. I will respond as soon as I have something to say :)

Comment: I don't see the problem with this.  It is perfectly reasonable (in fact, I claim *desirable*) to say that "Plain text" means "what the `Dynamic` displays).  In some fundamental sense, you are "displaying" the Dynamic to the exporter.  Would you really expect `Export["foo.png", expr]` to not render dynamics reference by `expr`?  Now, it might be that it's doing too much silly work in the case of some views.  But while I'd probably concede some of the details could be better managed, I think the fundamental direction of the implementation is right.

Comment: @JohnFultz Thank you for the explanation. But what if I want to export only *cached* (pre-rendered) versions of `Dynamic` saved in the Notebook (i.e. as when `DynamicUpdating -> False`)? My solution via adding `DynamicUpdating -> False` into Notebook code looks a bit ugly. Is there a better way? Also does `DynamicUpdating -> False` disable `NotebookDynamicExpression` and `CellDynamicExpression` (it is not exactly clear from the Documentation)?

Comment: `DynamicUpdating->False` doesn't cache anything into the notebook.  `MaintainDynamicCaches->True` does.  I would expect the combination of those two options probably does what you want, but I haven't tried it.  And yes, I would also expect `DynamicUpdating->False` to disable `NotebookDynamicExpression` and `CellDynamicExpression` for any notebook it's been set on.