# Convert expression to string in a reversible manner

Tags: export, import, conversion, input-forms

What is the best way to convert an expression to a string in a reversible manner?

I need a `toStr` function so that it is always true that

```
ToExpression@toStr[expr] === expr
```

[`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html) is not satisfactory because it may use special, irreversible formatting.  Example:

```
ToString[Graphics[{Circle[{0,0}]}]]
(* "-Graphics-" *)
```

In this case the problem is that it uses `OutputForm` by default. Requesting [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html) would solve this.  But then consider

```
Format[x, InputForm] = "foo"

ToString[x, InputForm]
(* "foo" *)
```

`x` does exist as a proper expression in-memory.  It can be written to disk by exporting to MX and then reliably re-imported.  I am looking for the same functionality, but through strings.

---

Note: I am aware that there are some expressions which can't be safely cycled through a string, or even through `Compress` or through MathLink.  An example would be

```
asc = <| a -> 1|>
a = 5;

asc
(* <| a -> 1|> *)

ToExpression@ToString[asc]  (* or use Uncompress@Compress[...] if you like *)
(* <| 5 -> 1 |> *)
```

I am not aiming to solve these types of difficulties, which are separate from my main problem.

Comment: Related: "[How to convert arbitrary raw boxes directly into String?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115407/280)"

Comment: `InputForm` does not actually solve this completely, as it returns `"Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}]}]"`

Comment: @Feyre That's due to `Circle[]` evaluating to `Circle[{0,0}]`.  I changed the example to read `Circle[{0,0}]` to avoid misunderstanding.  I do not need to prevent evaluation, just to cycle an expression through a string reliably.

Comment: How about a cases structure, where it can evaluate to `ToString[HoldForm[a]]` if necessary?

Comment: Can using `"ExpressionJSON"` help?  For example, `str=ExportString[Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}]}], "ExpressionJSON", 
 "Compact" -> True]` then `ImportString[#,"ExpressionJSON"]&@str`.

Answer (score 3):

This may fail in some obvious way, but it works on the example you give

```
toStr = ToString@*FullForm
```

For example with the following

```
testcases = {Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}]}], Series[Sin[x], {x, 0, 3}], Integrate[f[x], x]}
```

I have

```
strs = toStr/@testcases
results = ToExpression /@ strs
testcases === results
(* True *)
```