# How to stop `Format` from evaluating when doing `Put`/`Export`?

Tags: export, output-formatting, output

If I do

```
Format[$hello, StandardForm] := "world"
```

then

```
Put[HoldComplete[Format[$hello, StandardForm]], "file.m"]
```

or

```
Export["file.m", HoldComplete[Format[$hello, StandardForm]]]
```

`file.m` will contain

```
HoldComplete["\"world\""]
```

How do I get literally

```
HoldComplete[Format[$hello, StandardForm]]
```

in the exported file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Block[{Format},
   Put[
      HoldComplete[Format[$hello, StandardForm]],
      "file.m"
   ]
]

FilePrint @ "file.m"
test = Get @ "file.m"
FullForm[test]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Export["file.m", FullForm@HoldComplete[Format[$hello, StandardForm]], "String"]
```

works, but all operators will be eliminated because of FullForm:

```
FullForm@HoldComplete[Format[$hello, StandardForm]*2]
```

> HoldComplete[Times[Format[$hello, StandardForm], 2]]

Comment: This is related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124677/12  Not that you can set a Format for FullForm too!  It is unlikely that anyone would do so, but it is possible.