# How to make some RowBox to be string

Tags: string-manipulation, conversion, boxes

```
GeneralUtilities`GetUsages["System`Sin"]
```

[image]

I want to get $\color{red}{\textbf{1}}$ plain string,but this function actually will give me some `RowBox`:
[image]

And the same case:

```
GeneralUtilities`GetUsages["System`Plot"]
```

[image] 
I want to get $\color{red}{\textbf{4}}$ plain string from it:

> {"Plot[f,{x,Subscript[x, min],Subscript[x, max]}] generates a plot of
>   f as a function of x from Subscript[x, min] to
>   Subscript[x,max].","Plot[{Subscript[f,
>   1],Subscript[f,2],…},{x,Subscript[x,min],Subscript[x, max]}] plots
>   several functions Subscript[f,i].","Plot[{…,w[Subscript[f, i]],…},…]
>   plots Subscript[f,i] with features defined by the symbolic wrapper
>   w.","Plot[…,{x}∈reg] takes the variable x to be in the geometric
>   region reg."}

Can any method do this?

Comment: @Kuba I have,we can *copy it as plain string* to get it by right click.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[How can I get the unchanged Box form of an arbitrary expression?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13317/5478)

```
toBoxes = MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
    FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[#, True]
][[1]] &
```

[How to convert arbitrary raw boxes directly into String?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/115407/5478)

```
toText = FrontEndExecute[
    FrontEnd`ExportPacket[#, "PlainText"]
][[1]] &
```

```
Composition[
    Map[toText]
  , Map[toBoxes]
  , StringSplit[#[[1]], "\n"] &
] @ GeneralUtilities`GetUsages["System`Plot"]
```

> ```
> {
>  "Plot[f,{x,Subscript[x, min],Subscript[x, max]}]generates a plot of \
>  f as a function of x from Subscript[x, min]to Subscript[x, max]."
>  ,
>  "Plot[{Subscript[f, 1],Subscript[f, 2],\[Ellipsis]},{x,Subscript[x, \
>  min],Subscript[x, max]}]plots several functions Subscript[f, i]."
>  , 
>  "Plot[{\[Ellipsis],w[Subscript[f, i]],\[Ellipsis]},\[Ellipsis]]plots \
>  Subscript[f, i]with features defined by the symbolic wrapper w."
>  ,
>  "Plot[\[Ellipsis],{x}\[Element]reg]takes the variable x to be in the \
>  geometric region reg."
> }
> ```

Comment: Good lesson to me.Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm shy to say I don't know the function of ``FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket`` still.And the function of the `True`?

Comment: @yode I can't say more than you can find in the topic linked above.