# How to change the terminal size programmatically that is opened by `RunProcess`?

Tags: interoperability, windows, linux, command-line

Why isn't the following linux command working from the `RunProcess` interface? I want to change the terminal size programmatically and then display the information:

```
commands[sequence__]:=StringJoin@Riffle[{sequence}," && "];
bashMode=commands[
    "echo Status for device CON:",
    "echo ----------------------",
    "echo '\tTerminal Type: $(tput longname)'",
    "echo '\tLines: $(tput lines)'",
    "echo '\tColumns: $(tput cols)'",
    "echo '\tColors: $(tput colors)'"
];
RunProcess[{"bash","-c",commands[
    "printf '\\e[8;24;90t'",
    bashMode
]}]
```

Since I don't know linux very well. If there is a way to join these commands into one, feel free to suggest that as well!

By the way I am on Windows and accessing bash through the `Windows Subsystem for Linux`.

---

I think the problem here might be `ASCII control character ESC` needed in the `printf` command to control the terminal: `printf '\e[8;24;90t'`. Since running this directly works but for some reason mathematica is unable to send this character to the bash correctly.

See: [Bug report about escape characters not going through bash](https://superuser.com/questions/666632/resizing-a-terminal-within-tmux-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: Does that even open up a terminal? I thought it just ran the command and gave you the output

Comment: `RunProcess[{"bash", "-c", "echo \"lines\\ncols\"|tput -S"}]` might give some insight as to the output you can expect here.

Comment: @user6014 Terminal should exists since `tput longname` does return its name. Also you can change properties like `color`, etc. But it is hidden like when using `WebExecute` you can launch a browser in hidden mode. Under mathematica subprocesses in Task Manager you can see the `Console Window Host` while the `RunProcess` is running.

Comment: From within a .bat file, the size of the command window can be set, for example, by the command `mode con:cols=200 lines=35`.

Answer (score 3):

## Update

It may be easier to just use the [`Run`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Run.html) command.  The following uses the `terminfo.sh` script that I described below.  Because `bash` does not like carriage returns, `\r`, you must remove them when export the script.  It also adds a `sleep 4` command so the window stays opened for 4 seconds before closing.

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
cmdstring = StringReplace[
   "#!/bin/bash

   echo Status for device CON:
   echo ----------------------
   echo \"    Terminal Type: $(tput longname)\"
   echo \"    Lines: $(tput lines)\"
   echo \"    Columns: $(tput cols)\"
   echo \"    Colors: $(tput colors)\"
   ", "\r\n" -> "\n"];
Export["terminfo.sh", cmdstring, "String"];
Run["cmd /c  \"MODE CON: COLS=50 LINES=8 && bash -c ./terminfo.sh; \
sleep 4 \""]
```

[image: Console Animation]

## Original Partial Answer

Controlling the window size may be a little tricky since as you suggested in the comments that it uses `Console Window Host`.  If you just want to see the default terminal properties, this seems to work on my Windows 10 system.

```
cmd = "echo Status for device CON:
  echo ----------------------
  echo \"    Terminal Type: $(tput longname)\"
  echo \"    Lines: $(tput lines)\"
  echo \"    Columns: $(tput cols)\"
  echo \"    Colors: $(tput colors)\"";
RunProcess[{"bash", "-c", cmd}, "StandardOutput"]
(* "Status for device CON:
----------------------
Terminal Type: xterm with 256 colors
Lines: 24
Columns: 80
Colors: 256
" *)
```

Alternatively, you could write a multiline bash script like and save it in `terminfo.sh` in the `NotebookDirectory`

`#!/bin/bash
echo Status for device CON:
echo ----------------------
echo "    Terminal Type: $(tput longname)"
echo "    Lines: $(tput lines)"
echo "    Columns: $(tput cols)"
echo "    Colors: $(tput colors)"`

Now you can call the script from `RunProcess` like so

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
RunProcess[{"cmd", "/c", "bash", "-c", "./terminfo.sh"}]
(* <|"ExitCode" -> 0, "StandardOutput" -> "Status for device CON:
  ----------------------
      Terminal Type: xterm with 256 colors
      Lines: 24
      Columns: 80
      Colors: 256
  ", "StandardError" -> ""|> *)
```

You may need to change the permissions on `terminfo.sh` to make it executable.  The easiest way to do that is in the `bash` shell with `chmod +x terminfo.sh`.