# MakeExpression can't deal with FE boxes riffled with whitespaces

Tags: bugs, front-end, conversion, boxes

**Bug introduced in 8 or earlier and persisting through 12.0**

> CASE:3910218

---

When you input

```
{ 1 , 2 } (*spaces intended, retype them if you want to copy this*)
```

The underlying structure (*<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>*) is:

```
boxes = RowBox[{"{", " ", RowBox[{"1", " ", ",", " ", "2"}], " ", "}"}]
```

You can evaluate input cell or do something like

```
ToExpression[boxes]
```

> {1,2}

and it works nicely, **however**:

```
MakeExpression[boxes, StandardForm]
```

> Syntax::sntxf :  "{ " cannot be followed by "1 , 2 }".
>
> ErrorBox[RowBox[{"{", " ", ErrorBox[RowBox[{"1", " ", ",", " ", "2"}]], " ", "}"}]]

### Questions

1. Is this a bug or have I missed something?
2. What would be the best workaround?

   `MakeExpression[boxes /. " " -> Nothing, StandardForm]` looks fine
3. What does the FrontEnd do before sending boxes for evaluation, LinkSnooper shows that `" "` are not present when the content is sent:

   ```
   EnterExpressionPacket[
       MakeExpression[
          BoxData[RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"1", ",", "2"}], "}"}]]
        , StandardForm
       ]
   ]
   ```

Comment: Have you tried `Trace[ToExpression[boxes], TraceInternal -> True]`? It calls `StripBoxes` as the first step which removes the redundant spaces. Then the output is sent to `MakeExpression` which returns `ErrorBox[ErrorBox[RowBox[{"1", ",", "2"}]]]` as intermediate result. But I don't understand why this intermediate result is ignored and the expected output is returned nevertheless.

Comment: From the Docs for [`StripBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StripBoxes.html): "When boxes are sent by the front end to the kernel for evaluation, the front end strips the boxes using a more extensive process that may depend upon active stylesheets and front end option settings. However, when working with functions that directly serialize notebook constructs such as `NotebookRead`, no stripping will occur."

Comment: As a workaround `MakeExpression[StripBoxes@boxes, StandardForm]` seems to work (but note the citation in the previous comment: "... the front end strips the boxes using a more extensive process ...").

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Ah, I was aware of StripBoxes but didn;t have time to play with Trace, also I didn't know if `ToExpression` does the same thing as what is done at Shift+Return event. p.s. I think `StripBoxes` is worth an answer,

Comment: I've checked it with version 5.2 and the behavior is exactly the same despite the Docs claiming that `StripBoxes` is introduced in version 6.0 (actually `StripBoxes` was [present already in version 3.0](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/Qlb4j8ezoMI/dPLbwTlhtNwJ)!). I'm pretty sure it isn't a bug, just incomplete documentation on the difference between `ToExpression` and `MakeExpression`.

Comment: Documented, though I don't know when this appeared: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StripBoxes.html#1490617234

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tracing the evaluation with `Trace[ToExpression[boxes], TraceInternal -> True]` reveals that `ToExpression` calls `StripBoxes` as the first step which removes the redundant spaces. So the obvious workaround is

```
MakeExpression[StripBoxes@boxes, StandardForm]
```

which seems to work.

Note however that according to the Docs page for [`StripBoxes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StripBoxes.html),

> When boxes are sent by the front end to the kernel for evaluation, the front end strips the boxes using a more extensive process that may depend upon active stylesheets and front end option settings.

Comment: `StripBoxes` is what I use now as `" "` is not the only problem it seems. Multi space `"    "` is just another example. And all this is what I get from `Boxes` `InputField`.

Comment: I faced another issue, please check this `MakeFormattedBoxes@Plot[Sin @ x,
       {x, 0, (3 + TemplateSlot["x5"])  Pi},       ImageSize -> 200      ]` if you wrap this with `RawBoxes` and evaluate the outpput cell you get it will work fine. `ToExpression @ StripBoxes @ MakeFormattedBoxes[...]` does not work though. Any ideas? I'm hesitating if it is worth another question.

Comment: @Kuba John Fultz: ["... there are some boxes, most notably TemplateBox, which require FE secret sauce to properly convert into expressions. "](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/112392/toexpression-and-toboxes-arent-inverses-of-each-other/112491#comment340550_112491)

Comment: There are no special boxes there, the couse seems to be unorthodox RowBox placement. I could do Flatten->StringJoin->MakeExpression but it feels like an overkill.

Comment: @Kuba Then it may worth a separate question.

Comment: @Kuba As John Fultz stresses in the comments linked above, we should realize that the expression - boxes - expression route isn't reliable. They just attempt to make it as realible as possible, but it still have many limitations. The fact that boxes can be rendered by FE doesn't mean that `ToExpression` can convert them into a valid expression.

Comment: This discussion is about converting back and forth. I'm only talking about getting any expression from valid boxes. And it does not contain any special boxes or custom built ones.

Comment: @Kuba Then it definitely worth a separate question in this general form with the explanation how it differs from the question I linked to. Or you can ask John directly in the comments under linked answer.

Comment: @Kuba As I understand, you still wish to obtain at least equivalent expression, that's the difference?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a bug. `MakeExpression`, as a low-level function, only deals with canonical boxes as sent by the FE. Sometimes you get lucky with non-canonical boxes, but there's no guarantee. `ToExpression`, which is a more user-friendly function, will apply `StripBoxes` first, which attempts to simulate the canonicalization performed by the FE, so it will work on more cases (except for the occasional bug in `StripBoxes`, in which case you might end up with wrong thing).

The documentation example referenced in the comments was added in 12.1, but this has been the intent forever.  It is perhaps still underdocumented.

BTW, newer versions of the kernel will attempt to ask the FE, if it is available, to resolve template boxes--and make their best guess from Core.nb if it is not available.  Hence, John's statement about only the FE knowing the how to resolve some boxes, while still true, is not as relevant as it used to be.