# How to change the default stylesheet?

Tags: fonts, style

How to change  $\textbf{default} $ output font color in *Mathematica*?

for instance :

how to set following style as default

[image]

And

how to set the default magnification to 200% instead  100%

[image]

Comment: Changing the magnification: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/59149/18476

Comment: There were some time ago "Notes on Creating Style Sheets" by David Park. He published them on MathGroup at that time. It is a very nice and comprehensive explanation which I use ever since. However, I do not think it is possible to publish here a document of somebody else. You might, however, want to ask him directly. In such a case go to his homepage, https://davidandalicepark.wordpress.com/home-2/about-3/ where you will find his e-mail.