# Cannot save plots, WindowSize error

Tags: export, warning-messages, save

Every time I attempt to save a plot by right clicking and clicking "Save Graphic As..." I get an error "The specified setting for the option WindowSize cannot be used". I am completely at a loss to explain this, this just started about a week ago. I can save them as PDF's, but not .gif, .jpeg, .png, etc. I can save in any format by using `Export` but this is still annoying. Any insight into what could be causing this?

Comment: I have found the answer here: [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16539/failure-to-export-graphics-by-right-click-when-notebook-magnification-is-changed?rq=1). Surprised this bug has not been fixed already.

Comment: I can't reproduce it on Win10 V11.2. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Win10 V11.0